# How to write a case when statement when there are overlaps in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

[image]

How can I group it to this

[image]

Small is the sum of the count when Count <25; Large is the sum of the count when Count>=25; Total is the sum of all counts.

Comment: going forward ,please paste table data and expected output as text and also try posting your attempt..check this link on why images are not good :https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2975396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ID INT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
    nCount int NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (ID, nCount) VALUES
    (1, 10), (2, 15), (3, 22), (4, 23),
    (5, 25), (6, 27), (7, 30);

--=====================================

WITH 
    cte_Totals AS (
        SELECT 
            Total = SUM(td.nCount),
            Small = SUM(CASE WHEN td.nCount < 25 THEN td.nCount ELSE 0 END),
            Large = SUM(CASE WHEN td.nCount >= 25 THEN td.nCount ELSE 0 END)
        FROM 
            #TestData td
        )
SELECT 
    x.[Group],
    x.[Count]
FROM 
    cte_Totals t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, 'Total', t.Total), (2, 'Small', t.Small), (3, 'Large', t.Large) ) x (SortBy, [Group],[Count])
ORDER BY 
    x.SortBy;
```

Results...

```
Group Count
----- -----------
Total 152
Small 70
Large 82
```

HTH,
Jason

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT
     SUM(Count) as Total,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Count <  25 THEN Count ELSE 0 END) as Small,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Count >= 25 THEN Count ELSE 0 END) as Large
FROM table
```

Comment: almost - OP wanted it in columns

Answer (score 3):

Late answer (**keep the accepted as is**), but I did want to introduce a concept which may be more helpful down the line.

I maintain a generic Tier Table.  The following is a simplified example, but you can take the aggregation tiers out of the code, and put it in a table... things change, and you can serve multiple masters.

**Sample Data**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[Count] int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1, 10), (2, 15), (3, 22), (4, 23), (5, 25), (6, 27), (7, 30)

Declare @Tier table (Tier varchar(50),Seq int,Title varchar(50),R1 int,R2 int)
Insert Into @Tier values
 ('MyGroup',1,'Total',0,99999)
,('MyGroup',2,'Small',0,25)
,('MyGroup',3,'Large',25,99999)
```

**The Actual Query**

```
Select T.Title
      ,[Count] = sum(D.[Count])
 From  @Tier T
 Join  @YourTable D on (T.Tier='MyGroup' and D.Count >= T.R1 and D.Count<T.R2)
 Group By T.Title,T.Seq
 Order By T.Seq
```

**Returns**

```
Title   Count
Total   152
Small   70
Large   82
```

> **EDIT - There are many ways you can construct this**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID varchar(50),[Count] int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Tywin', 10), ('Tywin', 15), ('Tyrion', 22), ('Bran', 23), ('Ned', 25), ('John', 27), ('Robb', 30)

Declare @Tier table (Tier varchar(50),Seq int,Title varchar(50),R1 int,R2 int,C1 varchar(50),C2 varchar(50))
Insert Into @Tier values
 ('MyGroup',1,'Total'  ,null,null,'a','z')
,('MyGroup',2,'Group 1',null,null,'Tywin,Tyrion',null)
,('MyGroup',3,'Group 2',null,null,'Bran,Ned,John,Robb',null)


Select T.Title
      ,[Count] = sum(D.[Count])
 From  @Tier T
 Join  @YourTable D on T.Tier='MyGroup' and (D.ID between C1 and C2 or patindex('%,'+D.ID+',%',','+C1+',')>0)
 Group By T.Title,T.Seq
 Order By T.Seq
```

**Returns**

```
Title     Count
Total     152
Group 1   47
Group 2   105
```

Comment: Wow. That works as a charm if the boundaries are defined as numbers.

Comment: @kzhang12 Sorry didn't have my glasses when I "read" your comment.  My real structure has N1 - N2 (numerics),  C1 - C2 (varchar), and D1 - D2 (dates).   So I can apply what ever tier/grouping I need

Comment: @kzhang12 I should add, a LEFT JOIN will display all tiers even if there are no hits.

Comment: If it is a manual grouping process, e.g. when name in ('Tywin', 'Tyrion'), group them as 'Group1'; when name in ('Bran', 'Ned', 'John', 'Robb'), group them as 'Group2', will your magic still work?

Comment: @kzhang12 Yes, but you can use the IN clause unless you are going with some dynamic SQL.  You can have multiple rows Bran > Group2 or in the join patindex.

Comment: Wow. That is really amazing!

Comment: @kzhang12 Too kind.  I'm just a lazy coder.  I would rather have my data drive the process than the code.  Besides. I know things change, and I can have alternate tiers for Senior Managers... still the same report, just different parameter,